# Create page header and details sections

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created four database fields: `ChargesView`, `CommodityView` `GeneralInfoView` and `LumpsumView`

So I want `ChargesView` with header and its details, `CommodityView` with header and its details.

Ex:
I want crystal reports to be like:

Report Header
Page Header
Details
Pageheader
Details
Report Footer
Page Footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't insert a PageHeader between 2 Details.

In this case, you have to use sub-reports.

Right click on DetailSection > Insert Sub-report > Choose an preexisting report or create a new one.

A subreport is a report item that displays another report inside the body of a main report.

Answer (score 0):

Use subreports for the Details section

Write a subreport for `ChargesView`'s Details section. Write another subreport for `CommodityView`'s Details section. Place these subreports into separate Details sections for your main report, and activate `New Page After` for both sections.

---

If you need the Page Header to change based on which subreport is being displayed, you can make multiple Page Headers and suppress them based on a shared variable. (When your `ChargesView` section displays, set the shared variable to `charges`. Then have the `Charges` header only display when your variable is equal to `charges.)